# Rails - What is the best way to display default avatar if user doesn't have one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Right now, each time I need to display a user's avatar, I have if statements that check whether they uploaded an avatar or not. I know it's definitely not DRY if I have these statements littered through my html.

So, what's the best way to find out which image to display?

Edit: I'm using Carrierwave (Paperclip didn't work for me for some reason)

Comment: Are you using a gem for your avatar uploads? Like Carrierwave or Paperclip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using helper methods.That should solve your worries. Your helper would be like

```
def check_avatar(user)
     if user.image.nil?
       # return default image
    else
       #return user avatar
    end
end
```

The usage in your views would be 
`check_avatar(user)`

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with Paperclip

You can add the following to your User-Model (app/models/user.rb):

```
has_attached_file :avatar, default_url: "avatar.png"
```

You have to place your Image into

```
app/assets/images/
```

Comment: Do you know how to do this with Carrierwave?

Answer (score 1):

It is documented in CarrierWave's repo.

https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#providing-a-default-url

> ## Providing a default URL
>
> In many cases, especially when working with images, it might be a good idea to provide a default url, a fallback in case no file has been uploaded. You can do this easily by overriding the default_url method in your uploader:

```
class MyUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def default_url(*args)
    "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  end
end
```

> Or if you are using the Rails asset pipeline:

```
class MyUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def default_url(*args)
    ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If your avatar URL is stored USER.AVATAR in your DB, then:

```
class User
  DEFAULT_AVATAR = "xyz"
  def avatar
    read_attribute('avatar') || DEFAULT_AVATAR
  end
end
```