# How can I set a default image for user in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, simple-form-for

I am trying to set a default image for users when they sign up. They can change that if they prefer and otherwise a default image will be given. The `input_html`, however, doesn't seem to work?

How can I set a default image?

Current simple form for input:

```
<% default_picture = (image_path 'user.png') %>
<%= f.input :avatar, input_html: {value: '#{default_picture}'}, label: false %>
```

Comment: How are you expecting this to work? Should the field be a file uploader, or are you selecting from a number of pre-defined avatars? This looks like a simple text field, is that what you want?

Comment: If you want set default value for some attributes, you can use callback:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1551430/2640181

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `before_create` in your model, to set the default image.

```rb
before_create :set_default_avatar

def set_default_avatar
  # your code
end
```

and here other discussion regarding about your question,  [Rails - What is the best way to display default avatar if user doesn't have one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35937493/rails-what-is-the-best-way-to-display-default-avatar-if-user-doesnt-have-one)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Does this work with CarrierWave as well? The avatars which are referenced (even when nil) have a lot of information so im not sure I can set the default image directly as described?

Comment: yes it work well with carrierwave as well, you need to change `before_create` into `after_create` and add logic if image is nil than process with upload file, and also you can try follow this documentation from carrierwave https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-%22Upload%22-from-a-local-file , and also with carrierwave you can provide default url if the image is blank https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#providing-a-default-url .

Comment: are you using device? if you set `after_create` at the `User` model, you could access the attributes with `self.avatar = uploaded_image` , `current_user` is not accesible in the model.

Comment: Yes I just thought of that before commenting so I removed that comment!

I am really close.... when I set the avatar myself with current_user.avatar = imgpath it works. However when I want it to be done after_create with self.avatar = imgpath it doesnt work?

Comment: My if statement was incorrect!!! It was `if self.avatar?` instead of `if !self.avatar?` . Everything fixed!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

> You don't need to work with a form of default image when user not uploaded any image. You can just use a static image when user's `avatar` is empty. Just call out a default image

The right way to the set using user default image, you can create a helper method to any helper file like `helpers/application.html.erb`

```
def avatar_for(user)
    @avatar = user.avatar
    if @avatar.empty?
        @avatar_user = image_tag("user.png", alt: user.name)
    else
        @avatar_user = image_tag(@avatar.url, alt: user.name)
    end
    return @avatar_user
end
```

if `user.avatar` is empty then it will show the default `user.png` from `assets/images` folder otherwise it will show a user's uploaded the image

and put the image `user.png` to `assets/images/` folder

Then you can just callout from `.html.erb` file like this

```
<%= avatar_for(current_user) %>
or
<%= avatar_for(@user) %>
#just pass user object from anywhere
```

Or if you need to show the image with different sizes for a different place then it would be like this

```
def avatar_for(user, width = '', height = '')
    @avatar = user.avatar
    if @avatar.empty?
        @avatar_user = image_tag("user.png", alt: user.name, width: width, height: height)
    else
        @avatar_user = image_tag(@avatar.url, alt: user.name, width: width, height: height)
    end
    return @avatar_user
end
```

Then callout like this

```
<%= avatar_for(current_user, 100, 100) %>
```

Or you can use [`gravatar`](https://en.gravatar.com/) for default `avatar`

```
def avatar_for(user)
    @avatar = user.avatar
    if @avatar.empty?
        gravatar_id = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(user.email).downcase
        @avatar_user = "https://gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}.png"
    else
        @avatar_user = image_tag(@avatar.url, alt: user.name)
    end
    return @avatar_user
end
```

You can see the full tutorial for generating gravatar avatar image from [`RailsCast`](http://railscasts.com/episodes/244-gravatar?view=asciicast)

Comment: So I have to create this helper file first correct? I found another file which is called application_helper.rb, could I put this code in there as well? Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to create another one helper file, you can this with which helper file already exists like `application_helper.rb`